# БД Delphi не запускается на другом компьютере

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Есть база Delphi, алиас задавал через BDE администратор. 
Можно как то сделать, чтобы на другом компьютере запускалось без BDE?

Comment: Delphi - это не база данных, а язык программирования и среда разработки. Уточните, какую именно базу данных вы использовали в своей программе. Или хотя бы, какие компоненты доступа.

Answer (score -1):

если программа настроена на доступ к данным "через BDE администратор", то ответ очевиден: НЕТ